# Map MVC View Route Values to physical path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

Say I have a route value for a path that has a view, like

```
new
{
    controller = "Home",
    action = "Index"
}
```

How do I map this to `~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`?

I know not all views necessarily have an action, and that not all actions necessarily return a view, so that might prove to be an issue.

## Update:

Maybe something like this:

```
IView view = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(ControllerContext, "Index").View;
view.GetViewPath();
```

But that allows me to specify a controller instead of assuming I want to use my controllerContext (or maybe even mocking up a controllerContext for the Controller (string) I want..

Comment: I can't understand. What's wrong with MVC built-in routing system?

Comment: The built-in routing system is fine, but I needed to convert `viewName`/`controller` pairs back to physical paths in order to simplify the parameters taken by a method that rendered partial views, instead of having to pass a full physical path, now I can just pass the `viewName` and the `controller` name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I've done it:

```
private string GetPhysicalPath(string viewName, string controller)
{
    ControllerContext context = CloneControllerContext();

    if (!controller.NullOrEmpty())
    {
        context.RouteData.Values["controller"] = controller;
    }
    if (viewName.NullOrEmpty())
    {
        viewName = context.RouteData.GetActionString();
    }
    IView view = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(viewName, context).View;
    string physicalPath = view.GetViewPath();
    return physicalPath;
}
```

and the extension method for `GetViewPath` is:

```
public static string GetViewPath(this IView view)
{
    BuildManagerCompiledView buildManagerCompiledView = view as BuildManagerCompiledView;
    if (buildManagerCompiledView == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        return buildManagerCompiledView.ViewPath;
    }
}
```

and `CloneControllerContext` is:

```
private ControllerContext CloneControllerContext()
{
    ControllerContext context = new ControllerContext(Request.RequestContext, this);
    return context;
}
```

Comment: Never heard about `.NullOrEmpty()` method!

Comment: just syntactic sugar for `string.IsNullOrEmpty`, it's an extension method.

Comment: This is a well-hidden bit of knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

From RazorViewEngine.cs (in the mvc3 source), the search paths for views are as follows (assuming razor):

```
    ViewLocationFormats = new[] {
        "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
        "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
    };
```

{1} refers to the controller routevalue, and {0} is the view name (not part of the routevalues).

You can search these locations to try to find a view which matches your criteria but you also need to understand quite how many assumptions you are making...i.e. that the view has the same name as the action (by default yes, but not if you specify a view name in the call to View in the controller's action). You've mentioned a couple of other assumptions already

Comment: You have assumed that the view has the same name as the action in the answer you have posted here: viewName = context.RouteData.GetActionString();

Comment: that's not assuming anything, that's Mvc's own convention, if you `return View()` you get the view which maps to the action being requested, I needed something similar.